Union of sets and union of set differences
In JK Hunter's measure notes, I read:
If $\{A_i: i ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ is an increasing sequence of sets and $B_i = A_{i+1}\setminus A_i$,
then $\{B_i : i ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ is a disjoint sequence with the same union (...)
Basically the author is saying that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}$$
But as far as I can see the correct equation would be
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i}=\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}B_{i}\right)\cup A_1$$
What am I missing?

I believe $B_0 = A_1$ is the only initial condition that makes sense and should have been mentioned. This makes what the author is saying to be the same as your equation.

I think you're right. The author presumably meant to say $B_1 = A_1$ and $B_{i + 1} = A_{i + 1} \setminus A_i$. Or alternatively, you can assume WLOG that $A_1 = \emptyset$, because making $A_1$ smaller does not affect the union or the limit. I think the author was probably "on autopilot" when writing this proof and made a simple oversight/typo.

What OP gave is a valid way to fix the typo. Beyond the additional ways to fix the typo given by LocalNondeterminism & IzaakvanDongen , there is a 4th way : $\mu(A_1)=0$ , which works within the context of the Proof given there. I would go with "every $B_i$ , except $B_1$ , is a Difference , while $B_1$ is $A_1$ itself" , which is simple to interpret !

Thank you all for confirming this was a simple typo/oversight by the author. I want d to make sure I'm not missing anything.
